# es.merge doesn't merge my streams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, angular-template

I have the following gulp task:

```
var es = require('event-stream'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');

var scripts = gulp.src(paths.js + '/**/*.js'),
    templates = gulp.src(paths.templates + '/**/*.html')
        .pipe(templateCache('templates.js', {
            module: 'spot.im.core',
            standalone: false
        }));

es.merge(templates, scripts)
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
```

When running this, I don't get the templates inside all.js. But, when I am doing:

```
es.merge(templates)
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
```

all.js contains the templates.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to define a task here; and, you can replace event-stream with merge-stream instead. I've had no trouble running merge-stream in many gulp tasks.

```
var merge = require('merge-stream'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    var scripts = gulp.src(paths.js + '/**/*.js');
    var templates = gulp.src(paths.templates + '/**/*.html')
        .pipe(templateCache('templates.js', {
            module: 'spot.im.core',
            standalone: false
        }));

    return merge(templates, scripts)
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});
```

Run on the command line with `gulp`.